# Effects of accidental ketosis on training

Tags: endurance

I sometimes go into ketosis *accidentally* (please keep those dieting people away from me) during endurance training or shortly afterwards. Now for the first time since acquiring a 24h-hr-monitor.

- I noticed an abnormal increase in rhr after the latest accidental ketosis (+13-15 on the next day instead of the usual +2-3 after the most intense workouts that I do. That's close to a 30% increase). Does ketosis really cause rhr spikes like that? I found various people telling the internet it was true, but nothing reliable. Someone on a forum for people who intentionally go into ketosis and who usually has a rhr of over 80 is not a reliable source.
- I guess like usual I should wait with intense workouts until the rhr is somewhat normalized again? I will wait until the ketosis goes away in any case and will see if the rhr normalizes at the same time.
- How bad is ketosis for training effect?

(I didn't select the ketogenic diet tag because I'm **not** on a ketogenic diet and would *never* enter ketosis on purpose. I actively try to eat lots of carbs before, during and after long exercise sessions. I'm just not doing a good enough job of it, it seems)

Comment: How do you know you go into ketosis? Do you monitor your blood sugar level? I wonder whether you actually mean ketoacidosis rather than ketosis, which I will call a normal metabolic process.

Comment: @Gyrfalcon I might be using the terms wrong. I don't monitor blood sugar level and have no medical history of diabetes or anything. What I mean is that state after a at the very least several hours of intense exercise where I feel stupid, tired, groggy for several days. I was taught that was called ketosis and was caused by too many ketons in the blood as a by product of rapidly breaking down fats which the body isn't used to do. The way I get rid of it is by eating lots of carbs and doing little exercise, supposedly most of the negative effects also go away when the body gets used to it.

Comment: I do have a history of eating irregularly and most of the time when I encounter those symptoms I either did 8-12 hours of bicycling or realize in hindsight that those 4 hours were still too much considering I forgot to eat enough before and during. So the explanation makes sense to me.

Comment: I did not realize you were doing extreme sports. It is likely you are right about a very high ketone level, and you can do a self-test using [urine sticks](https://www.ketogenicsupplementreviews.com/ketone-urine-strips/)
Anyway, for a better response I suggest you change the question to *what you do inclusive preparation, what you observe, and then ask how you can avoid this unwanted state*. Also be accurate about your HR: Include [HR recovery](https://www.livestrong.com/article/378549-my-heart-rate-stays-high-after-a-workout/), and how many hours your resting HR stays increased.

Comment: @Gyrfalcon Thanks, that was helpful, I'm going to buy some tests for next time. I'm pretty sure I know how to avoid the problem in theory, I just mess up in practice. I was mostly interested in some more background about what happens in the muscles and the rest of the body and how that affects recovery. But I'm kind of busy and have no time to improve the question or transform it into another (also interesting) one. Whatever.